# How to search for int instead of a string, sqlite database, android

Tags: android, sqlite

I wanted to search the database table for the row with an int value,  not a string value, but when do this I get an error. So I wish I could do this however it is not possible:

```
  updateRow(int titleCode, int questionCode, int inspectionResult){
```

So instead I am stuck with this,

```
  updateRow(String titleCode, String questionCode, int inspectionResult){
```

How can I use the selection args like this;

```
 new String[]{titleCode, questionCode}
```

to search for titleCode and questionCode if these variables are int/integer and not Strings?

as the fact that I cannot change the selection args array from a String type to an int type yet I want to search for int values in the database table

```
         public void updateRow(String titleCode, String questionCode, int inspectionResult){

             ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
             String selection = "INSPECTION_PLACE_CODE = ? AND INSPECTION_ITEM_CODE = ?";
             contentValues.put(INSPECTION_RESULT_JUDGEMENT, inspectionResult);
             sqLiteDatabase.update(DETAILS_TRAN_SMALL_INSPECTION_RESULTS, contentValues, selection,
             new String[]{titleCode, questionCode});

         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Based on section 3.3, comparisons, including equality checks are subject to type affinity. You can safely test int values as Strings in SQLite because the database driver will auto convert your String to an int before comparing.